# Linq MaxBy with all elements?

Tags: c#, linq, max, .net-6.0

I would like to get ALL elements in enumerable whose property is the maximum :

```
IEnumerable<Person> allOldest = people.GroupBy(p => p.Age)
    .OrderByDescending(i=>i.Key).First().Select(_=>_);
```

.NET 6 introduce `MaxBy` which return THE max item:

```
Person uniqueOldest = people.MaxBy(person => person.Age);
```

`MaxBy` can't help me ?
Is there another more elegant solution than first example?

Comment: Is it important to you that you only iterate over the input once? If not, you could just use `Max` to get the maximum value, then `Where` to get all the elements with that value.

Comment: Thank you Jon. why not. but is it more optimized than 1 iteration ?
i think big enumaration and many times and if applicable EF conversion in SQL

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "more optimized than 1 iteration" - and if you need this for EF, please state that in the question, as it may well make any number of other answers inappropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Max` is a simple plain way of doing this:

```
var maxAge = items.Max(y => y.Age);
var maxItems = items.Where(x => x.Age == maxAge);
```

Comment: ok but maxItems is IGrouping<int, Person> 
use Select(_=>_) after for select Person

Comment: I refactored my answer, please take a look.

Comment: This approach has the potential problem of enumerating the `items` twice. This can be a problem if the `items` is a deferred enumerable, connected to a database or some other not in-memory source of data.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias even not twice but `items.Count() + 1` times which is far worse =)

Comment: @GuruStron you are right. But after the latest edit by Ran Turner, my initial comment still holds. 

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with adding an external dependency to your project, you could install the respectable [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) package (originally developed by the one and only [Jon Skeet](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jon-skeet-the-chuck-norris-of-programming-ee5781c7e18a/)) and do this:

```
IEnumerable<Person> allOldest = MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable.MaxBy(people, p => p.Age);
```

The signature of the [`MoreEnumerable.MaxBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MaxBy__2.htm) method:

```
public static IExtremaEnumerable<TSource> MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector);
```

You could also try to use it as an extension method, by adding this `using` directive at the top:

```
using static MoreLinq.Extensions.MaxByExtension;
```

...but in .NET 6 this will result (most likely) in a name resolution conflict.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those times that linq isn't necessarily the best option.  You could create a linq style extension to do it but really the most direct solution is just to write a function.  Here's a simple example.  I've used a value tuple as a stand in for your person object.

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        var source = new (int key, int value)[] { (0, 0), (1, 5), (2, 1), (3, 5), (4, 0), (5, 5) };

        var allMax = new List<(int, int)>();
        int currentMax = int.MinValue;

        foreach (var (key, value) in source)
        {
            if (currentMax < value)
            {
                allMax.Clear();
                allMax.Add((key, value));
                currentMax = value;
            }
            else if (currentMax == value)
            {
                allMax.Add((key, value));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{allMax.Count} Max valued items found");

        foreach (var (key, value) in allMax)
            Console.WriteLine($"({key}, {value})");
    }
```